# combine two array as key value pair

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have two array as follows

```
        var field_array=["booktitle","bookid","bookauthor"];
        var data_array=["testtitle","testid","testauthor"];
```

I want to combine these two array and covert it to the following format

```
    var data={
    "booktitle":"testtitle",
    "bookid":"testid",
    "bookauthor":"testauthor"
}
```

I want to insert this data to database using nodejs

```
var lastquery= connection.query('INSERT INTO book_tbl SET ?',data, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {

             res.redirect('/list');
  }else{
      res.redirect('/list');
  }
});
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

```
var field_array = ["booktitle", "bookid", "bookauthor"];
var data_array = ["testtitle", "testid", "testauthor"];
var finalObj = {};
field_array.forEach(function (eachItem, i) {
  finalObj[eachItem] = data_array[i];
});

console.log(finalObj); //finalObj contains ur data
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in a similar way:

```js
var field_array=["booktitle","bookid","bookauthor"];
var data_array=["testtitle","testid","testauthor"];
var result = field_array.reduce((acc, item, i) => {
  acc[item] = data_array[i];
  return acc;
}, {}); 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here I explaned my code line by line..Hope it will help

```
        var field_array = ["booktitle", "bookid", "bookauthor"];
        var data_array = ["testtitle", "testid", "testauthor"];

        //Convert above two array into JSON Obj
        var jsondata = {};
        field_array.forEach(function (eachItem, i) {
            jsondata[eachItem] = data_array[i];
        });
        //End

        //Store Jsondata into an array according to Database column structure
        var values = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++)
            values.push([jsondata[i].booktitle, jsondata[i].bookid, jsondata[i].bookauthor]);
        //END

        //Bulk insert using nested array [ [a,b],[c,d] ] will be flattened to (a,b),(c,d)
        connection.query('INSERT INTO book_tbl (booktitle, bookid, bookauthor) VALUES ?', [values], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
        res.send('Error');
        }
        else {
        res.send('Success');
        }
        //END
```

Comment: if both are dynamic array how to  modify the code ?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic array?

Comment: Ok I got it..in case of dynamic array choose that key from jsondata Object to which you want insertion. Can you share me your database table structure? So that i can give you clear explanation through code